# Problem adding bundle products to cart

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

OK I really dont get this, I am trying to add a product to the cart and save the quote, this is working great for simple products but I can not get the bundle products to work here is my code

```
        $params = array(
            'product' => $addId, // the bundle product id
            'qty'     => $addQty, // the qty of the bundle product
            'options' => $optsArray,  .. used for simple products with options

            'bundle_option' => array(
                251 => 1, // add 1 X product 251
                250 => 1, // add 1 X product 250
                249 => 2 // add 2 X product 249
            )

        );

        $quote->addProduct($addProduct, new Varien_Object($params));
        $quote->save();
```

I dont understand what I am doing wrong any help would be greatly appreciated, I cant seem to find what variable sthe bundle_options array expects

Answer (score 0):

OK so I found the solution which works perfectly for me I set set the product options like so

```
$params = array(
        'product' => $addId, // the bundle product id
        'qty'     => $addQty, // the qty of the bundle product
        'options' => $optsArray,  .. used for simple products with options
    );
```

And then for the default bundle items which I set when I set the products up at the back end

```
        if($addProduct->getTypeId() == 'bundle') {
            $selectionCollection = $addProduct->getTypeInstance(true)->getSelectionsCollection(
                $addProduct->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($addProduct),
                $addProduct
            );
            foreach($selectionCollection as $option) {
                $bundleOption[$option->getOptionId()]       = (int)$option->getSelectionId();
                $bundleOptionQty[$option->getOptionId()]    = (int)$option->getSelectionQty();
            }
            if(!empty($bundleOption)) $params['bundle_option'] = $bundleOption;
            if(!empty($bundleOptionQty)) $params['bundle_option_qty'] = $bundleOptionQty;
        }
```

Basically this just gets all the listed child products of the bundle and adds them to the params array with the default qtys.

I no there may be other ways of doing this but thought I would post my answer to help fellow developers in need